# perl Net::DNS weird error (root servers "did not give answers")

Tags: perl

I'm trying to install Net::DNS as part of setting up ASSP Deluxe.  I've installed my own 5.14.1 perl on a CentOS box, and when it tries to 'make test' Net::DNS, I get:

```
Servers [202.12.27.33 193.0.14.129 192.112.36.4 198.41.0.4 192.5.5.241 192.228.79.201 128.63.2.53 128.8.10.90 192.203.230.10 192.58.128.30 192.36.148.17 199.7.83.42 192.33.4.12 ] did not give answers at /build/Net-DNS-0.72-KhhIcm/blib/lib/Net/DNS/Resolver/Recurse.pm line 110.
```

This message will repeat forever in the logs.

This is really strange, since those IPs are root servers.

I can nslookup those IPs and in general, DNS is working fine on the box.  I've googled for this error but can't find any answers...indeed, I find a few scattered cases where people have asked the question:

- http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Perl/comp.lang.perl.misc/2004-03/1795.html
- http://spamassassin.1065346.n5.nabble.com/Net-DNS-t-10-recurse-test-fails-tt39666.html#none
- https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-66840.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Those servers don't recurse - they will only answer for root domains, e.g:

```
#dig  @199.7.83.42 fubar.it

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13856
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 12
====>;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fubar.it.                      IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
it.                     172800  IN      NS      a.dns.it.
....

# dig +short  @199.7.83.42 fubar.it
[nothing]
```